# How to show error message from implemented custom validator in JSP view?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, jsp

I am writing a custom validator. It should just compare 2 field values in the form and reject if they are same. It successfully rejects, but I can not send my error message to the view.

This is my custom validator class:

```
public class CheckSameNameValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return FormModel.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        FormModel model = (FormModel) target;
        if (model.getPerson1().getName().equals(model.getPerson2().getName())) {
            System.out.println("error occurred");
            errors.reject("person can not relate to himself!");
        }
    }

}
```

This is the FormModel class used in validation:

```
public class FormModel {
    private Person person1;
    private Person person2;

    public Person getPerson1() {
        return person1;
    }

    public void setPerson1(Person person1) {
        this.person1 = person1;
    }

    public Person getPerson2() {
        return person2;
    }

    public void setPerson2(Person person2) {
        this.person2 = person2;
    }
}
```

This is the controller method used:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/setRelative", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView setRelative(@Valid @ModelAttribute("people") FormModel people, BindingResult bindingResult,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        logger.info("set relative controller");
        CheckSameNameValidator validator = new CheckSameNameValidator();
        validator.validate(people, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
            model.setViewName("index");
            model.addObject("people", people);
            return model;
        } else {
  }
}
```

And this is the form in jsp:

```
<f:form class="form-inline" action="setRelative"
    modelAttribute="people">

    <label>Person:</label>
    <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="person1.name" items="${nameList}"
            multiple="false">
        </f:select> 
        <f:errors path="person1.name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>

    <f:label path="person2.name">Relative:</f:label>
    <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="person2.name" items="${nameList}"
            multiple="false">
        </f:select> 
        <f:errors path="person2.name" class="alert alert-danger"></f:errors>

        <label>Person's Relation to Relative:</label>
    <f:select cssStyle="width:150px" path="person2.relations"
        items="${relationList}" multiple="false"> 
    </f:select>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Set
        relative</button>

</f:form>
```

I expect the error message to be printed to the view, if error occurred. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to add this message in the controller `model.addObject("message", "your error message");`
and then, put in you jsp `${message}` where you want to show it.

It's another option to print the message in the jsp.I hope to help you.

Comment: Oh, this has really helped me, thank you, I have used it now like this: `model.addObject("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors().get(0).getCode());` and this gives me the error code